# Get rectangles that are farthest away from a center rectangle

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

How can I achieve the reverse of a k-nearest search, so that I can find geometries thar are farthest away from a given center geometry?

Background: This is about map tile caching. I want to remove irrelevant tiles which are far away from the current view.

Comment: In geometry it is usually nice to have some kind of abstract data type in order to sort/search geometries. Such as a quad-tree or a bsp/kd-tree

Answer (score 1):

The furthest rectangles are always at the limits. So you need to get the minimal enclosing circle, which is defined by three extremal points. The most distant from  any given point within the minimal enclosing circle is then the nearest to the most distant point on the circle, which is found by taking a ray from the point in question through the origin until it hits the circumference.

So if you need many most distant neighbours, you set up a structure which tags each arc of the minimal enclosing circle with its nearest neighbour, then you can find them quickly.

However it's unlikely you actually want this. You have a rectangle of interest, and now simply exclude everything outside of it.